# Cannot upload Product image after migration

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I recently migrated my magento site from one server to another but I noticed I cannot upload images, actually when i cleared image cache, all product images disappeared. Here is a screenshot of the error received.

[image]

I have given suggested permissions to the respective folders but I am still experiencing the same issue. I noticed the product image was been pulled from /media/catalog/product/cache. Once i deleted that folder, all product images from frontend disappeared, however, backend images are showing

Comment: Sounds like your `media` directory isn't writable by the web server, try the following command if you have SSH access: `find . -type d -name 'media' -exec chmod 2775 {} \;`

Comment: @MattAntley it didnt work. I have tried 777 too

Answer (score 0):

Check the Permissions on your new server.
Most likely the media/tmp directory is your issue.
Either the Owner of the directory is not your server's user.
Or it just doesn't have enough permissions granted.

Comment: I have given suggested permissions to the respective folders but I am still experiencing the same issue. I noticed the product image was been pulled from /media/catalog/product/cache. Once i deleted that folder, all product images from frontend disappeared, however, backend images are showing